# Adding a Elassandra tag

Tags: feature-request, tag-creation

It seems like we should have an [Elassandra](https://www.elassandra.io/) tag in here, especially given that it exists on Stack Overflow. Is there any reason why we can't add it in, or why it hasn't been added already? Elassandra is tightly integrated with both Cassandra and Elasticsearch, and so it seems like the site for DBA's would be a most natural place for it.

Comment: Why does it seem to you that we need this tag? It's unclear from your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We didn't have the tag since [your question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/269803/67785) is currently the [only question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=elassandra) about it. I've edited it in (with your help) but at the same time I fear the question itself might be a bit too broad.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, just went in and made the question more specific, hopefully that is better

Answer (score 1):

I'm fine with having the new product / new tag here. It may be a while until network effects of questions and expertise accumulates, of course. Every other tag has had its first question at some point.